# How To Use CompUtil To Parse With Plugin

Tags: alloy

When using the Alloy API to perform parsing on the following string:

```
Module mod = CompUtil.parseEverything_fromString("run {} for 5")
```

I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error:
Parser Exception
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.parser.CompParser.alloy_parseStream(CompParser.java:2260)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.parser.CompUtil.parseRecursively(CompUtil.java:178)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.parser.CompUtil.parseEverything_fromFile(CompUtil.java:280)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.parser.CompUtil.parseEverything_fromString(CompUtil.java:333)
    at edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.parser.CompUtil$parseEverything_fromString.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at MyOM.MyOMPlugin.Modularize(MyOMPlugin.groovy:107)
    ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class file:

package MyOM

class MyOMPlugin extends Plugin{  
        void Modularize() throws Err{
                 //line 107 is the only line in the method and is below
                 Module mod = CompUtil.parseEverything_fromString("run {} for 5")
}
}
```

I am performing this task in a groovy class file within a groovy project. The code works fine until I run it in conjunction with the plugin I am using.

EDIT:
The parse function is what causes the parse exception and the code for that method is included below for reference:

```
 @Override public Symbol parse() throws java.lang.Exception {
     int act; // current action code
     Symbol lhs_sym = null; // the Symbol/stack element returned by a reduce
     short handle_size, lhs_sym_num; // information about production being reduced with
     boolean logging = "yes".equals(System.getProperty("debug"));
     production_tab = production_table();
     action_tab     = action_table();
     reduce_tab     = reduce_table();
     init_actions();
     user_init();
     // start
     cur_token = scan();
     stack.removeAllElements();
     stack.push(getSymbolFactory().startSymbol("START", 0, start_state()));
     tos = 0;
     for (_done_parsing = false; !_done_parsing; ) {
        act = get_action(((Symbol)stack.peek()).parse_state, cur_token.sym);
        if (act > 0) { // "shift"; thus, we shift to the encoded state by pushing it on the stack
           if (logging) System.out.println("shift " + cur_token.sym);
           cur_token.parse_state = act-1;
           stack.push(cur_token);
           tos++;
           cur_token = scan();
        } else if (act<0) { // "reduce"
           if (logging) System.out.println("reduce " + ((-act)-1));
           lhs_sym = do_action((-act)-1, this, stack, tos);
           lhs_sym_num = production_tab[(-act)-1][0];
           handle_size = production_tab[(-act)-1][1];
           for (int i = 0; i < handle_size; i++)  {  stack.pop(); tos--; }
           act = get_reduce(((Symbol)stack.peek()).parse_state, lhs_sym_num);
           lhs_sym.parse_state = act;
           stack.push(lhs_sym);
           tos++;
        } else { // "error"
           if (logging) System.out.println("error");
           syntax_error(cur_token);
           done_parsing();
        }
     }
     return lhs_sym;
  }
```

Comment: Catch the exception and look at the cause of the exception. You might need to do this recursively

Comment: @Peter the exception comes from the parse function in the CompParser.java file. A try catch is put around p.parse() and the parse function is ultimately what throws the exception. I have added the code for reference in the question.

Comment: If you run it in a debugger you can set a breakpoint and use the Debug Shell to figure out the underlying exception

Comment: @Peter the issue is not happening when I just run the code in Java, so the debugger idea won't work. The issue is happening when I run the code as a plugin for an application.

Comment: In your code, catch the exception and recursively call `getCause()` and printout the exception. This should bring you to the real cause. Java exceptions are brain damaged unfortunately